# Internet History Eraser?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, privacy

I'm looking for eraser tool that can erase all history, not only browsing one but also search and Windows apps history. The visited web sites trouble me too, is this a type of internet history or something else?

Comment: What is the browser?

Comment: My advice: stop visiting troubling sites, and after this, browse in a [Sandboxie](http://sandboxie.com/) session.

Answer (score 8):

While not the application's sole purpose, [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) can remove browser history for the major browsers, deletes Flash local objects, clears temporary files, and can even remove Windows's recently run lists for applications. Another nice feature is that you can "preview" your actions before running them, to see exactly what all will be deleted.

Comment: Depending on just how paranoid you are, you should consider running [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/) after CCleaner and setting it to overwrite all empty space on your harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. The browser stores the web pages you have visited and then shows this information, so anybody can see what sites you have visited.It's called Recently history.

As for me, I use Mil Shield, it works well on my 64 bit system and cleans all computer/Internet/Application/Search Engines history.

Here are its download and reviews:
http://download.cnet.com/Mil-Shield/3000-2144_4-10493437.html?tag=mncol

Answer (score 1):

**Viruses, malware**

This should go unsaid, but if you are trying to scrub a computer like your question suggests, you'll also want to check for any viruses or malware with an antivirus program. You can always uninstall the antivirus program if you don't want it there when you are done.

**Browser History, Cookies, Temp Files, Downloaded Files**

Is nhinkle suggested, [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) is an easy way to go if you're using a mainstream browser. If you're using something else, you'll need to check your manual on how to do this.

**Applications Installed in the timeframe**

Firstly, Windows will know what you've installed when. You'll want to uninstall any programs that were installed durring this timeframe. [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) can also do this for you (and shows you the installation date).

**Application History**

Windows keeps a log application events. I'm not for sure on the rules of what is and isn't logged, but I'm pretty sure you will want to clean this out as well. [Here's instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3wah3h5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

**Windows Search History**

For [Windows XP](http://www.winxptutor.com/searchmru.htm), or for [Windows 7](http://www.killertechtips.com/2009/05/06/clear-explorer-search-history-in-windows-7/).

**Registry**

Changes to the registry are a fairly common thing, so this is also something to investigate. The downside is that I can't find any programs that can analyze programs made to the registry *after* it's been installed, it seems they can only track changes made to the registry *while* the program is installed. Something else for you to consider.